# Two java files in same package but still getting error can't find symbol : class (using intellij IDE)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

two java files one is main.java and display.java in same package still i am getting (can't find class error),i hope the code is fine but i am new to this intellj IDE ,so i'cant fix this problem
i had code below:

```
Main.java
---------
package com.gamebox;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display start = new Display();

    }
}

Display.java
------------
package com.gamebox;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Display {
    private JFrame jframe;
    private int height,width;
    private double[] size;

    public void Display(){
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Game");
        getSystemSize();
    }

    public void getSystemSize(){
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screenSize = tk.getScreenSize();
        double[] arr = new double[2];

        arr[0] = screenSize.width;
        arr[1] = screenSize.height;

        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        // return arr;

    }

}
```

[image: both files in same folder]

Comment: How are you source files setup? Are they in the same folder? What folder is your source root?

Comment: yes,its in same folder

Comment: Why are you using the terminal? Your main class seems fine, it isn't marked by intellij as having a problem.

Comment: when i use run button ,everything run fine with zero error. but not even a print statement working inside that function .that show it don't call that display function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also don't call the "public void Display ()" function. You create an instance of the display object in the main method, with its Default-Constructor. And the Default-Constructor contains no method or print-statement or whatever. If you change the following in the Main method: 
`Display start = new Display ();
start.Display ();` it will give you the output. But think of methodNames should be start with lowercase-letters and camelCased.

Comment: it worked thank so much matt ,but i have doubt .i just created default constructor ,hence do i want to call using start.display(),  as soon as the object created .it should call is n't it ?

Comment: If u want to call the method, when the Object is created, just move the corresponding method to the constructor. `public Display(){
        Display();
    }` in your Display object and then you can call `Display start = new Display()` and your method will be executed, when the Display-Object is created

Comment: @anbu I would like to point out that you *can* call the method from the constructor, but it is somewhat bad practice. It is good practice to keep work done in your constructor minimal. So `Display display = new Display();` then call the method you want `display.Display()`.

Comment: thank you so much ,yes constructor as no return type .hope i wont forget this, here after ,this is really so help full .once again thanks a lot .i was struck with this error more than a hour .

Comment: Abstract classes can not be instantiated. So you can't do something like that Display start = new Display() because you can not create an Instance of that Class. You can use an abstract class to define general methods and the create subclasses of this class, which can be instantiated. So the subclass inherits from the parent-class. And you use a constructor to get access to the properties, or mehtods of that object. So i don't no exactly what you mean with project load. I recommend to read some articles or books about java and/or Object-oriented-Programming.

Comment: can you tell a real time example where to use constructor..(is there any other chat option in this stackoverflow instead of comment option)